# Is there a way to get the value within a <div> using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to python and webscraping so I'm not sure what the name of the value inbetween the `<div>`'s in an element is called. Sorry for not being able to specify.

```
<div class="syllable">value</div>
```

Is there a way to have the value inbetween the `<div>`'s get assigned to a string variable in python using selenium using XPath?
For example, the "value" in the element would be a string and it would print out:

```
value
```

I'm new to python and selenium so I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

To print out the text of the element.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_class_name("syllable")
print(elem.text)
```

xpath:

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='syllable']/text()")
print(elem)
```

Answer (score 2):

it is called html innerText

you can retrieve this value using text in selenium , or get_attribute.

This returns the rendered text (means displayed text)

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_class_name("syllable")
print(elem.text)
```

This return the text with out checking the style attribute meaning returns value even if its not displayed in UI

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_class_name("syllable")
print(elem.get_attribute("textContent")
```

you can find elem using this text also:

```
// partial match
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(),'value')])
print(elem.text)

// exact match 
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='value')])
print(elem.text)

// exact match of the elements text if there is any child element like span it won't return the element
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='value')])
print(elem.text)
```

Also note:

Other things you could read about outerHTML , innerHTML

Answer (score 2):

To print the *text* `value` you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `class_name` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("syllable").get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.syllable").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='syllable']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CLASS_NAME` and `get_attribute("textContent")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "syllable"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.syllable"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='syllable']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  value
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)